# background not being displayed in IE but works fine in Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have the following html code

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-back">
<img id="bg" src="background.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" >
</div>
<center>
<div id="content" align="center"><br>
<a href="#">Souvenir</a><br><br>
<a href="#">Gallery</a><br><br>
<a href="#">Presentations</a><br><br>
<a href="#">Principal's Message</a><br><br>
<a href="#">About</a><br><br>
</div></center>
</body>
</html>
```

and **CSS:**

```
@charset "utf-8";
html { 
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
body {
    overflow-y:auto;
}
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#page-back {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}
#content {
    width: auto;
    height: 530px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#content a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
```

This code works fine in Chrome, but in IE the image

```
<img id="bg" src="background.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" >
```

is not being displayed. Tried a lot of things but nothing works !

What should be changed ?

Thank you

Comment: ... And if you change it to IE8 Standards Mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding position:relative; to the #bg tag. My guess is that because you're using z-index, something else might be on top of it, causing it not to display. If not let me know and i'll help work through this.

The #page-back having position absolute might also be causing this problem.

Comment: that didn't make any change ! @Barret

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CSS property `background-image` (on your html for example) to set a background image for your website, I don't think you'll have any compatibility problem this way.

Comment: that didn't help @Zealot